# Category-selector in Cart Price Rules freezes

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.2.4

I have only barely used the CPR before, but I seem to remember it working fine. Now I'm set to enter some discount codes, but don't want them to apply to sales items.
I figure I could solve this by either setting the Special Price attribute to be used in CPR. Or put them into a separate category and filter that.

Problem is; whenever I try to select a category, the entire page freezes. And I can never get any filters for attributes. (See screenshots).

Anyone got any ideas as to why these may crash?

M 2.2.4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGEUc.png)

[image]

Edit: I see this is an official bug:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15121

Comment: Same problem is encountered on our magento install. Anybody has an idea of what is causing problem?

Comment: @EricTurcotte are you on 2.2.4 as well? not sure if it's related to the 2.2.4 upgrade; last time I tried was on 2.2.2 and I think that was fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Magento 2.2.4 bug.

For the lazy who don't want to search github for the fix, I'll post it here.

In `vendor/magento/module_catalog/view/adminhtml/web/js/category-checkbox-tree.js`

On line 171 change:

`for (i = 0; i < config.length; i++) {`

to

`for (var i = 0; i < config.length; i++) {`

and on line 188 change:

`for (i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; i++) {`

to

`for (var i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; i++) {`

or just update Magento to 2.2.5.